# How to bind array of values to nodeJs model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing **RESTful** API.
**Model**

```
    var productsSchema = new Schema({
        productName:{type: String, required: true},
        productDescription: {type: String, required: true},
        produtThumbnail:{type: String},
        productStock: [
        {
            size: {type: Number, required: false},
            price: {type: Number, required: false}
    }],
     productTags:[{
            tag: {type: String,  required: false}
        }]
});
```

**POST Method**

```
router.post('/api/new-product',upload.any(),function(req, res, next){

  console.log(req.body);
  if(req.files){
    req.files.forEach(function(file){

      var filename = (new Date()).valueOf() + '-' + file.originalname;
      fs.rename(file.path,'public/images/'+ filename, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file Uploaded');
        //Save to mongoose
        var product = new Products({
          productName: req.body.productName,
          productDescription: req.body.productDescription,
          size: req.body.productStock.size,
          productThumbnail: filename
        });
        product.save(function(err, result){
          if(err){}
            res.json(result);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}) <br/>
```

**Problem:**
I am able to bind object data to model, but I don't know how to bind array-data to model.
**For example**

```
var product = new Products({
          productName: req.body.productName,
          productDescription: req.body.productDescription,
          size: req.body.productStock.size,// This line doesn't work
          productThumbnail: filename
        });
```

`size:req.body.productStock` doesn't work
So, How can I bind array-data to model, and then save it to mongodb?
Please help..

Comment: In your mongoose, `required: false` is the default, therefore you don't need to add those. Also, you don't need to wrap your `tag` inside of an object if that's the only property to store

Comment: `required: false` , means my server will not throw any error, even if I skip this field, but I want to save this field value also in the dataBase.

Comment: But `required: false` is the default, right?

Comment: yes, it's right.

Comment: can you paste what's inside of `req.body` ? I can't seem to get your data structure, because your model does not equal the values that you save from the request.

Comment: I have updated my model, according to my request values.

Comment: No you haven't. You still use `size`, which is not defined in your Model. It is defined as part of a nested document array. Is `req.body.productStock` an object? in this case you should have `productStock: [ req.body.productStock]`. Best chance for you to receive a competent answer would be to paste your `req.body` as well.

Comment: yes, correct `size` is a nested part of `productStock[]` array.

Comment: I tried `productStock:[{
          size: req.body.productStock.size
        }
          ]`, now object is getting saved, but still no success with size field.

Comment: if `productStock` is an array. It should be `productStock[0].size`. Anyway won't be able to answer this one, since you don't want to include the req.body.

Comment: Hmm, I have posted the output

Comment: if productStock is an array. It should be productStock[0].size, but then this is static way, right. I mean we never know how many fileds will come in `productStock` array.

Comment: I am posting data like this  `{       "productName":"abc-product",
        "productDescription":"abc-product for sale" ,
        "produtThumbnail":"image.png",
        "productStock": [
        {
            "size":12 ,
            "price": 23
         },
         {
         "size":14 ,
          "price": 24
         },
          {
         "size":15 ,
          "price": 25
         }
    ]
}`

Comment: **req.body** :
`{ productStock: '[object Object],[object Object]',
  productName: 'new name',
  productDescription: 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
  otherProductAttributes: '[object Object]' }
`

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to type array

```
var productsSchema = new Schema({
        merchantId: {type: String, required: false},
        produtThumbnai:{type: String},
        productStock: {type: Array},
     productTags:{type: Array}
});
```

It Works!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just because of a typo, because your Schema looks OK. Change this:

```
var product = new Products({
    // ...
    size: req.body.productStock.size,
    // ...
});
```

To this:

```
var product = new Products({
    // ...
    productStock: req.body.productStock,
    // ...
});
```

For this to work **you should be passing your `productStock` as an array of objects from your POST request** (!)

Otherwise it's a bit difficult to offer you more help, since we are unaware of what req.body actually is.

---

**EDIT**

To check if the above works (and assuming you are passing `productStock` as a whole array of objects from Postman/Curl/whatever), do the following and paste the result here:

```
product.productStock.foreach( (product, idx) => console.log(`(${idx}):${product.id}, `) )
```

Comment: `product.productStock.foreach( product =>console.log(product.id) )`, output:(567897e667799)

Comment: **req.body** :
`{ productStock: '[object Object],[object Object]',
  productName: 'new name',
  productDescription: 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
  otherProductAttributes: '[object Object]' }
`

Comment: So it is working now right? Please check my new EDIT section, and give me the results you got here.

Comment: I am getting **Unexpected token** at  `{` (${idx}).

Comment: Why I am getting `productStock:'[object object],[object object]`?

Comment: I logged `product.productStock[0].size`, and I got **undefined**

Comment: It shouldn't give you the `unexpected token` error anymore. Run it and tell me exactly what it spits out

Comment: Got nothing as output.